# Setup Nginx + SSL + Spring MVC + Security

Tags: java, nginx, ssl, spring-security, wildfly

I have the following installation: Nginx + selfmade SLL cert + Wildfly running on the same host. On Wildfly I have Spring MVC app with context path /myapp  with Spring Security.
App is working perfectly when accessing it at http://192.168.13.13:8080/myapp (all pages, redirects, logins, etc.).
So I want to access it through Nginx and root context path, i.e. http://192.168.13.13/. And at this moment I'm stuck.
If I do not use SLL and proxying from / to / - it works. But I have to enter http://192.168.13.13/myapp to access http://192.168.13.13:8080/myapp.
If I set proxy from / to /myapp - all Spring redirects are broke.
If I enable SSL - I can't login to my app and Spring redirects also broke.

Could someone prompt for correct setup of my installation?

Current nginx config:

```
upstream wildfly {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=5;
}

server {
    underscores_in_headers on;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com; 
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    underscores_in_headers on;
    
    listen          443 ssl;
    listen          [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name     example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/self.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK'; 

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/self.crt;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass_header X-CSRF-TOKEN;
        proxy_pass http://wildfly/;
    }
}
```

Current Spring Security config:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/platform/**").authenticated()

                .and().cors()
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .addLogoutHandler(new SecurityContextLogoutHandler())
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().rememberMe().key("remembermekay").tokenValiditySeconds(60*60*24*14)
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/access_denied");
    }
```

If you need any other configs please ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution: in Wildfly I've configured virtual host and map it to my application. No other actions were required - now it's working as expected.

```
<host name="example.com" alias="example.com" default-web-module="myapp.war">
    <access-log directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}/access" prefix="myapp_access_log."/>
</host>
```